# Scrapy, get a href from inside a H3 tag?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Currently trying to scrape the link and title from the following piece of HTML and cannot seem to find any way of doing it despite reading the scrapy docs for a while.

```
<h3 class="data"> 
  <a href="example.com" title="uniqueTitle"></a>
</h3>
```

Whats the best way of doing this? Also I should note that there are many of these `<h3>` elements on the page with the same class but different `<a>` tags that I want to scrape.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the things that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the url within the `h3` tags, you can use e.g

```py
from scrapy import Selector
sel = Selector(text='''<h3 class="data"> 
  <a href="example.com" title="uniqueTitle"></a>
</h3>''')
print(sel.css('h3.data > a::attr(href)').extract()) # you can use this
```

Output:

```
['example.com']
```

Comment: If this answers your question, give me upvotes.

Comment: I am also trying to get the title from the <a> tag. I have tried `sel.css('h3.data > a::attr(title)').extract()` but for some reason that doesnt seem to work?

Comment: this `sel.css('h3.data > a::attr(title)').extract())` works from my end here

Comment: Good! What did you now adjust?